# How to cripple the prompt message in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I read my project code in vs code. However, I don't have to run it and thus I choose not to configure it. Unfortunately, each time I hit a file window, vs code would show me a error message. What's more, the message window rightly holds up my toolbar. It is annoying! >_<
How can I disable the function of showing error message?
I will appreciate it if someone could give me some advice.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is coming the [clang-format extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xaver.clang-format). You should [disable this extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_disable-an-extension) if you are not going to use it or configure it.

The error is expected and correct in this case as that extension will not work without a valid clang executable

Comment: Actually, I haven't installed this extension before. But I do it without disabling the extension after receiving your advice and this problem is fixed.